# HighCharts Does not display Graphics after hosting with Laravel Project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, highcharts

Before I hosted it, in the sense that it was still on localhost HighChart Work Properly, but after I hosted it, the graphics didn't appear.

Here is what my HighChart looks like on localhost:

[localhost HighCharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55HUC.png)

and this is how my HighChart looks after hosting:

[Hosted HighCharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtw7L.png)

This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let datakunjungperbulanchrt =  JSON.parse(`<?php echo $datakunjungperbulanchrt ?>`);
let datapinjamperbulanchrt =  JSON.parse(`<?php echo $datapinjamperbulanchrt ?>`);
Highcharts.chart('myChart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Jumlah pengunjung dan Jumlah Transaksi Bulanan'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    colors: ['#4E73DF','#F6C23E'],

     xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Jumlah'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jumlah Pengunjung',
        data: datakunjungperbulanchrt
    },{
        name: 'Jumlah Transaksi',
        data: datapinjamperbulanchrt
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
</script>
```

This is the code in the master.blade.php file:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Dashboard</title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/dropdownsearch.css')}}" type="text/css">
  <link href="{{ url('icon/css/all.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/customcol.css')}}" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('js/Chart.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="{{ url('css/sb-admin-2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

and this is the Code of the Dashboard Controller, namely DashboardController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Transaksi;
use App\Tamu;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {

    $datapinjamperbulan = Transaksi::whereMonth('tanggal_peminjaman','=',Carbon::now()->month)->count();
    $datapinjamperbulanchrt = Transaksi::select(\DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
                                ->whereYear('tanggal_peminjaman', date('Y'))
                                ->groupBy(\DB::raw("Month(tanggal_peminjaman)"))
                                ->pluck('count');

    $datakunjungperbulan = Tamu::whereMonth('tanggal_kunjungan','=',Carbon::now()->month)->count();
    $datakunjungperbulanchrt = Tamu::select(\DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
                                ->whereYear('tanggal_kunjungan', date('Y'))
                                ->groupBy(\DB::raw("Month(tanggal_kunjungan)"))
                                ->pluck('count');

    return view('admin.dashboard',[
        'datapinjamperbulan'=>$datapinjamperbulan, 
        'datapinjamperbulanchrt'=>$datapinjamperbulanchrt,
        'datakunjungperbulan'=>$datakunjungperbulan,
        'datakunjungperbulanchrt'=>$datakunjungperbulanchrt
    ]);
  }
}
```

Here is the result of the variable $datapinjamperbulanchrt:

[$datapinjamperbulanchrt Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rocp.png)

Here is the result of the variable $datakunjungperbulanchrt:

[$datakunjungperbulanchrt Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I91vL.png)

Comment: Seems that chart is rendered properly, but the data is missed. Try to render your chart asynchronously after fetching the data.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel i had try that but nothing happen this is $datapinjamperbulanchrt result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rocp.png
and this datakunjungperbulanchrt result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/I91vL.png

Comment: Your data result looks fine, but what I had in mind is the sequence of the code triggering. It seems that it happens synchronously and the chart is rendered before the data has been initialized.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel mean you mean variables must be executed first before calling data on series?

Comment: try to `console.log` the `$datapinjamperbulanchrt` just after his declaration and before the chart initialization. What is the output?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel after I tried console.log there was no error like the image below: https://imgur.com/a/rnc4vwN

Comment: Thank you for the image, I know where the problem is. Your output is an array of strings, but it should be an array of numbers. You need to parse it.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Oh thanks a lot this worked fine, I added a string array converter to the integer array like this:

    var datpinjamstr = datapinjamperbulanchrt.map(function(v) {
      return parseInt(v, 10);
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add Conversion String Array into Integer Array as below:

```
var datkunjungstr = datakunjungperbulanchrt.map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 10); });
var datpinjamstr = datapinjamperbulanchrt.map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 10); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts runs on the browser, so it should'nt matter if it is being served from a hosting or from localhost. Also, Highcharts is actually working, which is why you see that the chart is being rendered. The only thing is that the chart is missing the data.

Can you check if Highcharts is receiving data from PHP variables $datakunjungperbulanchrt and $datapinjamperbulanchrt?

Additionally,
Does the browser console show any errors? Please confirm if the JSON.parse is working correctly in the following lines:

```
let datakunjungperbulanchrt =  JSON.parse(`<?php echo $datakunjungperbulanchrt ?>`);
let datapinjamperbulanchrt =  JSON.parse(`<?php echo $datapinjamperbulanchrt ?>`);
```

Comment: the data should send fine through the database, as it is on localhost. I've added details about Dashboard Controller (DashboardController.php) I think the controller is not there something wrong?,

Comment: No error in console, i tried to alert data from variable and that work
like this : https://imgur.com/a/HAHQ1YV

this is the code : https://imgur.com/a/a8bIVmF